# Cannot enable 'Any organization's members' setting when creating Group or updating properties using ArcGIS Python API

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, grouping, create

I am creating a group using the ArcGIS for Python API, there is limited information in the API Reference [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.GroupManager.create).

And I found some more information in the [Rest Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/common-parameters.htm) relating to the membershipAccess property that it can be org | collaboration | none, and none is the default. The ArcGIS for Python API also indicates that the default is None based on the parameters for the create function.

The default, however, when I run the below snippet is that the membershipAccess property is set to org.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

agol = GIS("home")

agol.groups.create(
    title = "Test_Group",
    tags = ["Test", "Group"],
)
```

[image]

Even if I use the update function to update the membershipAccess to None it does not take.

What settings can I use to perform this action using the ArcGIS Python API, or is it simply a bug?

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

agol = GIS("home")

group = agol.groups.get("GROUP_ID")

group.update(
    membership_access = None
)
```

If I set manually to Any organization's members, and the query that property, the property does not exist, but it does exist when org or collaboration is set.

Comment: I think you've found a bug. I went into the actual API, and your keyword / param are correct: `membership_access=None`. Watching the request made in the home app on an `update` call shows `membershipAccess` is passed in _without a value_. I'd need to proxy the Python API to confirm that using `membership_access` is doing the exact same call: my guess is that it is not. You may want to raise a bug @ https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api

Comment: Bug submitted https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/1590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the update manually with the following code snippet. For whatever reason you need to pass in the `clearEmptyFields` along with the `membershipAccess` for it to set the value.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

agol = GIS("home")

g = agol.groups.create(
    title = "Test_Group1112",
    tags = ["Test", "Group"]
)

gId = g.id
params = {"membershipAccess": "", "clearEmptyFields":"true"}
update = agol._con.post("{}/sharing/rest/community/groups/{}/update".format(agol.url, gId), params)
print(update)
```