# Create a ArcGIS Online group with some specific settings using ArcGIS Python API

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online-webmap

Those line of code create a new group with some specific properties and settings. But its not working for  display_settings properties and Group membership settings (Who can view this group?) I set as "only group member".

Can any ArcGIS Python API reference sample code help to be able to set the settings?

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", "user_name", "password")
group_properties = {
"title": "My_Group",
"tags": "GIS",
"description": "Only for testing",
"access": "org",  # Set the access level (org, public, private)
"display_settings": "apps",
"is_invitation_only": 'True',
"leaving_disallowed": 'True'
}
new_group = gis.groups.create(**group_properties)
new_group.protected = True
new_group.update()
```

[image]

Comment: I've never used display_settings, but for the image for group membership see this post here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461728/cannot-enable-any-organizations-members-setting-when-creating-group-or-updati